# how to enforce https-only on incoming traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, https, webserver, playframework-2.6

My web application is on `GCP` and accepts requests on both `http` and `https`. I want to enforce `https` only connections without creating friction in user experience.

If I remove `http` then I am afraid that a user typing `http://mywebapp.com` will get `404`. Should the right approach be to accept requests on both `http` and `https` and redirect `http` requests (`303`) so that the client send the request again using `https`?

- Is doing above possible?
- Wouldn't that increase my traffic cost (on `gcp` due to redirection/duplicate requests)
- Is there some other better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is common for sites to upgrade to secure connections. The GCP load balancer can "upgrade" requests to HTTPS. Follow their [step-by-step documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect) to enable this.

> Is doing above possible?

Yes.

> Wouldn't that increase my traffic cost (on gcp due to redirection/duplicate requests)

Should be negligible as the redirect should be permanent (`301`), enabling clients to upgrade to HTTPS on subsequent requests.

> Is there some other better way to achieve what I want?

There are other ways. Whether it is “better” depends on your specific use case. One can perform a redirect at virtually any layer in an application. If you’re not doing anything particularly useful, aside from redirecting insecure to secure, then it's best to do so as fast as possible (e.g. load balancer). Servicing insecure requests that ultimately redirect will consume needless resources (connections, memory, etc.), so it’s best avoided.